# Initial value problem $dy/dx =\sqrt{y^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

how does one go about solving the IVP

$dy/dx = \sqrt{y^2}$ ; with $y(0) = C$ in the area of $x = 0$?

My solution:

$dy/dx = y$

$\implies$ $(1/y) dy = 1 dx$

$\implies$ $\int (1/y) dy = \int 1 dx$

$\implies$ $\ln |y| = x + c$

$\implies$ $y =  e^{x+c}$ .

However, checking the answer sheet to the problem, it says that the correct answer is $y=c\times e^x$.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: This solution is wrong when $C<0$. When $C<0$, the solution is $y(x) = Ce^{-x}$

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for all of your math formatting.

Comment: $e^{x+c}=e^c\times e^x=k\times e^x$, where $k=e^c$.

Comment: $\sqrt{y^2}=|y|$ which is not the same as $\sqrt{y^2}=y$.

Answer (score 1):

Remember $C$ is just a constant. Use properties of exponentiation
$$
y= e^{x+c}= e^x \cdot e^c= C e^x
$$
where $C= e^c$. So although the constants $c,C$ are different, the solutions are the same, e.g.
$$
2e^x= e^{\ln 2} e^x= e^{x+\ln 2}
$$
In this case, $C=2$ and $c= \ln 2$.